# NPM packages are stuck on installing in cmd windows

Tags: npm, npm-install

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtDO3.jpg)

Cant figure out the solution as to why its stuck on installing npm packages.
I've already downloaded node js as well as npm and checked their versions on cmd

Comment: Why do you know that it is stuck? Maybe you are installing just so many packages that it takes a long time?

Comment: I'm not installing any package by myself. When I select the format stylesheet CSS it gets stuck on installing npm packages. I've also tried creating multiple angular apps but the same thing happens with each one, it doesn't go further than installing npm packages it's just stuck there in cmd

Comment: Where do you select "format stylesheet"? How do you select it? Why would that trigger any installing? Also, if you create an angular app, it will of course install all needed npm packages. How long do you wait until you decide it is stuck?